# Prevent html2pdf from breaking a specific string

Tags: php, css, html2pdf

I am using a html2pdf library to output a simple text on a page, such as the following:

`<p> One of the most corrosive substances on the planet is C<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub></p>`

I have defined an absolute width for the container using a css rule and sometimes the formula part happens to hit the edge of the container so it breaks it on multiple lines, which is not acceptable.

I have tried quite few things.

- plain white-space: nowrap; on the container, no effect
- wrapping the formula in it's own space and specifying white-space: nowrap; just for it - no effect
- I have looked at the html2pdf css 2.1 compatibility documentation and cannot see anything that would be suitable.

I'd be happy if there was something that could be done with just a css property, however, I am open to other alternatives.

Comment: Tried to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Spaces are not a problem, the problem is that it breaks on a new line in the middle of a formula where I have used the sub tags.